# Multi-language site

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n, taxonomy-terms

I'd like to build a multilingual site and I am quite new to drupal, I was wondering if I could proceed in the following way:

I could tag my entries with the world "english" and "italian", then I could display pages only with such tags to filter my site...

Generally speaking, would I be able to filter my site by tag?

Would this option be feasible? What would be the best solution to my problem?

Many thanks for any answer!

Alex

Answer (score 2):

Use the native Drupal internationalization functionality. You can then configure how nodes of different languages are shown, but by default they are found at [lang_code]/node/123 - eg fr/node/123.

You can alter Views to only show content to users in their specified language. User language can be a configurable option or can be autonegotiated based on browser headers.

Internationalization is a big, difficult topic, which I'm sure you're beginning to realise as you work on your site! [i18n](http://drupal.org/project/i18n) module is a good place to start, as it provides many useful add-ons which extend the core Drupal i18n functionality.

Answer (score 1):

What version of Drupal are you using? As "cam8001" suggests, internationalisation is a huge topic, fortunately Drupal has some substantial functionality to help you out. Take a look at these resources to get a summary of the topic:

- Drupal 7: [HOW TO CREATE A MULTILINGUAL SITE ON DRUPAL7 PART-1](http://www.brightwebsitedesign.com/how-to-create-multilingual-site-using-drupal7-part1)
- Drupal 6 & 7: [Multilingual Guide, drupal.org](http://drupal.org/node/324602)

Perhaps most importantly know that multilingual support in Drupal has several different modules to create the functionality of a typical multilingual site. Which ones you choose to use is dependent on your needs.